# Dealing with Doctrine2 mapping/relationship in entities

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

I'm working with Doctrine mapping between three entities and some doubts come to me. The entities are `Natural`, `Legal` and `Orders` where one `Natural` can have many `Orders` and one `Legal` can have many `Orders` too. So in `Natural` entity I have a `OneToMany` bidirectional relationship to `Orders` this is the code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Orders", mappedBy="natural")
 */
protected $orders;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->orders = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Then at `Orders` entity I have this:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="NaturalPerson", inversedBy="orders")
 * @JoinColumn(name="natural_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
protected $natural;
```

Here are my doubts:

- Since I have a third entity: `Legal` should I follow the same procedure in order to make a relationship between `Legal` and `Orders`?
- Is not this a serious inconsistency to leave an empty column as the `Orders` belongs to a `Natural` or a `Legal` but not both of them?
- How I save the `Orders`? I should flush and persist the `Orders` first and then set the object for `Legal` or `Natural` so the method `setOrder()` should be on `Natural` and `Legal` right?

Hope any can help me to understand this and thanks in advance

**Proposal DB model**

Here is the DB model I have til now, it can be changed

[image]

Comment: Its better to have to 2 entities for Orders 1 for `NaturalOrders`  and other for `LegalOrders` as natural and legal doesn't belong to each other then why their associated orders should be maintain by single `Orders` entity think this way

Comment: Does your business model make sense for Natural and Legal to derive from the same base entity? That way, your Order entity would instead have `protected orderType` whose `targetEntity="baseOrderType"`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid having the model as I leave in the main post, what are your suggestion? Can you place a answer with some example code in order to get the idea?

Comment: @Alex yes, it have sense, see the model I attached at main post, maybe it's bad but is what I have anyway it can change at anytime and I'll discuss with client so don't worries and comment on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since I have a third entity: Legal should I follow the same procedure in order to make a relationship between Legal and Orders?

YES, it works.

> Is not this a serious inconsistency to leave an empty column as the Orders belongs to a Natural or a Legal but not both of them?

Serious? No! Maybe a small one, but which is simple is also easier to maintain so be KISS.

> How I save the Orders? I should flush and persist the Orders first and then set the object for Legal or Natural so the method setOrder() should be on Natural and Legal right?

Only persistence is required, you can flush all at the end.